# Javascript / ES6 forEach Issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop through an `Array` of `Objects`, modify each `Object`, and push the result into a new `Array`.

The `Objects` in the array have different values. When I examine the resulting `Array` all of the `Objects` all have the same value. They all  reflect the last `Object` in the original `Array`

For Example:

```
const a = { choo: 'choo' }
const b = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { foo: 'foo' } ]

let c = [];
b.forEach((item) => {
  c.push(Object.assign(a, {...item} ));
});
```

The result of `c`:

```
[ 
  { foo: 'foo', choo: 'choo' }, 
  { foo: 'foo', choo: 'choo' }, 
  { foo: 'foo', choo: 'choo' } 
]
```

I assume this is some sort of scope issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Expected results would be

```
[
  { foo: 'bar', choo: 'choo' }, 
  { foo: 'baz', choo: 'choo' }, 
  { foo: 'foo', choo: 'choo' } 
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to loop through an Array of Objects, modify each Object, and push the result into a new Array.

Sounds like what you want is `.map`, not `.forEach`.

> When I examine the resulting Array all of the Objects all have the same value. They all reflect the last Object in the original Array

This is because `Object.assign` *modifies* an object. You are modifying `a` several times and creating an array with several references to `a`.

The answer is to pass an empty object as the first argument to `Object.assign` (and use `map`). The use of `{...item}` is also meaningless, so I have replaced that with `item`:

```js
const a = { choo: 'choo' }
const b = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { foo: 'foo' } ]

const c = b.map((item) => Object.assign({}, a, item));

console.log(c);
```

**Edit:** If you actually do want to *modify* the original objects, you can do that by changing the order of the arguments to `Object.assign` so that `item` is first. I would not recommend this though:

```js
const a = { choo: 'choo' }
const b = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { foo: 'foo' } ]

const c = b.map((item) => Object.assign(item, a));

console.log(c);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: That doesn't mutate the original object though, and he said he *did* want to modify it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm guessing that OP just used a poor choice of words there, but fair enough. I've added an addendum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how `Object.assign` works: it modifies the target and returns it, it does not create a new object. All your results reference the `a` that you passed as the target.

You're looking for

```
const c = b.map(item => ({...a, ...item})); // with object spread syntax
```

or

```
const c = b.map(item => Object.assign({}, a, item)); // with Object.assign
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b.forEach((item) => {
  c.push(Object.assign(a, {...item} ));
});
```

Not `{...b}`, must be `{...item}`

Comment: Sorry, simplified my code for the question, I am using `{...item}`. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `{...b}` - you're copying *all* properties of objects in `b`, when you only want to copy the property of the item you're iterating over.

```js
const a = { choo: 'choo' }
const b = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { foo: 'foo' } ]
const c = [];
b.forEach((item) => {
  c.push(Object.assign(item, a));
});
console.log(c);
```

You also want the first parameter of Object.assign to be the object you're mutating.

Answer (score 0):

**Object.assign**, this function will make your **object a** changed, and return the reference of **object a**.

That means, you change the **object a** and push its reference to **array c** in each loop.

Finally, you will get the array c which includes three references of object a. This moment, a is **{ foo: 'foo', choo: 'choo' }** .

**HOW TO SOLVE?**

The key is, push the different reference to array c in each loop.

```
const a = { choo: 'choo' }
const b = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { foo: 'foo' } ]

let c = [];
b.forEach((item) => {
  c.push(Object.assign({}, a, item ));
});
```